Website Points to 502 Error w/ gunicorn & nginx. .sock file is not being created
I am attempting to set up a website right now with gunicorn and am receiving a 502 error. When I check my error logs, I see the following:
2024/04/17 03:46:28 [crit] 13153#13153: *3 connect() to unix:/home/jimmy/portfolio/peak.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 216.165.95.139, server: website, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/jimmy/portfolio/peak.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "website", referrer: "https://website/"


As mentioned in the title, peak.sock is not being created.
My permissions are set to the following:
drwxrwxr-x 2 jimmy jimmy    4096 Apr 17 02:21 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jimmy jimmy       0 Apr 17 00:54 code
drwxrwxr-x 3 jimmy jimmy    4096 Apr 17 01:22 env
drwxr-xr-x 5 jimmy www-data 4096 Apr 17 03:22 portfolio
drwx------ 3 jimmy jimmy    4096 Apr 17 00:51 snap

drwxrwxr-x 2 jimmy www-data 4096 Apr 17 02:50  __pycache__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jimmy www-data  341 Apr 17 02:36  peak.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 jimmy www-data 4096 Apr 17 01:22  templates
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jimmy www-data 1675 Apr 17 01:22 'udo journalctl -u peak.service'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jimmy www-data   64 Apr 17 02:49  wsgi.py


/etc/systemd/system/peak.service is the following:
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve peak Flask app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=jimmy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/jimmy/portfolio
Environment="PATH=/home/jimmy/portfolio/env/teton/bin:$PATH"
ExecStart=/home/jimmy/portfolio/env/teton/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/jimmy/portfolio/peak.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

/etc/nginx/sites-available/peak.conf is set to the following:
server{
        server_name jimmychen.xyz www.jimmychen.xyz;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/jimmy/portfolio/peak.sock;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jimmychen.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jimmychen.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server{
    if ($host = www.jimmychen.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = jimmychen.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name jimmychen.xyz www.jimmychen.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}

Interestingly enough, I can use
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app

but
sudo systemctl start gunicorn


yields
Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.
I'm at my wits end here, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
I have tried creating a gunicorn.service file of my own in /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
~                         

